# Make a view go vertical if other view tries to compress it horizontally with constraints?

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, nslayoutconstraint

Let's say you have a label on the right and another label on the left of a screen. Text on the left one can grow till the end of the screen. Is it possible to make constraints to push the left label down if the right one grows so big it starts to compress the left one?

Ps. without constraints it seems easy, but the question is about constraints

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to make constraints to push the left label down if the right one grows so big it starts to compress the left one?

Yes, but not by magic. You would need, in code, to detect that this has happened and actually change the constraints entirely in order to rearrange the labels.

A more common solution to this problem is to give the left label a fixed minimum size so that the right one cannot compress it beyond a certain amount. You can even let the right label grow to multiple lines.

Comment: Then the answer is no, because I wanted it to be without code only with constrains

Comment: Yes, then the answer is no. You cannot make constraints that will behave as you describe _all by themselves_. That is what I mean by "magic". :)